# On the geometric arguments used in Newton's *Principia Mathematica Naturalis Philosophae*

Tags: calculus, geometry, physics, math-history, proof-writing

When one reads Newton's *Principia Mathematica*, one is immediately aware of the complexity of the synthetic geometry that he uses to prove his propositions. This I understand because all of the necessary calculus is being described in geometric language. Fortunately for us lesser mortals, the mathematician-astrophysicist Chandrasekhar has written a book that rephrases Newton's arguments in the language of modern-day calculus. However, if we stick to Newton's way of doing things, how can we improve the rigor of his synthetic-geometric arguments?

Comment: Maybe you could give some examples from Newton? Synthetic descriptions of plane geometry after Hilbert have been pretty successful, also for non-Euclidean planar, but I'm not sure how that helps you.

Comment: I found this question when looking for explanations about geometric proofs on Principia. Obviously, there are several intricacies in the arguments and how he chooses to solve a particular problem "just" by drawing forms and relations to lines, angles and points. I came across the following book during my short research on this topic and I think it might help you, even after so many years https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-0-85729-329-9